# NSMutableArray, Adding / Removing objects?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch

Is this the correct way to pop objects off the front of an array. I was just curious as I was thinking there might be a method for NSMutableArray that returned a retained object. Just curious if I am getting this right?

```
// PUTTING OBJECTS IN
NSMutableArray *fgStore = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
for(int counter=1; counter<=5; counter++) {
    NSString *dataValue = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"DATA%d", counter];
    [fgStore addObject:dataValue];
    [dataValue release];
}

// TAKING OBJECTS OUT
NSString *saveMe = [[fgStore objectAtIndex:0] retain];
[fgStore removeObjectAtIndex:0];    
NSLog(@"SAVE: %@", saveMe);
...
...
[fgStore release];
[saveMe release];
```

gary

Comment: I now think I got the wording wrong in the above, with regards to "returned a retained object". What I think I was trying to say was a "managed object"? whereby I did not need to do a retain myself. Does that make sense?

Comment: “Retained” makes sense in this context. “Managed” does not, at least not for me.

Comment: Thank you, yes I see. Retained as in its returned with a retainCount of +1. Basically, I don't need to retain it, just release it when done. Much appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is exactly the way I would do it, I don’t think there’s another. By returning a retained object you would break one of the main rules of Cocoa memory management: Most of the time you only own the objects returned by `init…` methods and have to retain the rest.

Answer (score 1):

That code looks fine. The only thing you might want to keep in mind is that you can use autorelease to avoid the explicit releases when you're done. For instance:

```
for(int counter=1; counter<=5; counter++) {
    NSString *dataValue = [[[NSString alloc]
                             initWithFormat:@"DATA%d", counter] autorelease];
    [fgStore addObject:dataValue];
}
```

I don't believe there is any NSMutableArray method that returns a retained object. Remember that methods which return retained values have names which start with alloc, new, or copy.

Comment: Some people would frown on the autorelease, as they only use autoreleasing when necessary. (A matter of style, I guess.) Also, `NSString` has a convenience `stringWithFormat` class method, so that the `alloc` and `autorelease` pair is extra, but that’s nitpicking.

Comment: Yeah, good point about the NSString convenience method. That would make for the most readable code.

Comment: Thank you both, I was going for explicit release because I am working on the iPhone and I want to make sure that I manually free things to keep my memory footprint as low as I can. (i.e. not waiting for the autorelease pool to be drained) that was my reasoning anyways ...

Comment: Autoreleased objects are usually collected with the next runloop iteration, which means almost immediately. You don’t have to fear them unless you allocate *a lot* of memory in a loop. (I also code exclusively for the iPhone and use autoreleased objects even in games without scruples.) But I also opt for the explicit release, unless I already have an autoreleased object.

Comment: Thank you, I am only just starting out, so I have been trying to stay with the best practice way of working. Like you said, I nearly always use an explicit release, although sometimes you have to go with what you get back from a method.